# What am i doing wrong? (segmentation fault)

Tags: c, cs50

Caesar pset2 from cs50, it compiles but shows an error at the end. What am I doing wrong? I ran debug50 and it shows the error relates to the cipher string, but I am still very confused.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

string rotate (string text  , int key )
{
string cipher = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++)
{
    if (isalpha(text[i]))
    {
        cipher[i] = text[i] + key;
    }
    if (!isalpha(cipher[i]))
    {
        cipher[i] = cipher[i] - 26;
    }
        return cipher;
 }
 int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
if (argc != 2)
{
    printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
    return 1;
}
for(int i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]); i++)
{
    if(!isdigit(argv[1][i]))
    {
       printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
       return 1;
    }
}
int key = atoi(argv[1]);
string text = get_string("Plaintext:  ");
printf("Ciphertext: %s ", rotate(text, key));
```

}

Comment: `string cipher = 0` - you never allocate it.

Comment: In `if (!isalpha(cipher[i]))` suppose (with ASCII) you add `20` to `'Z'`, which is `'n'` that is still alphabetical character, but the wrong one. The overflow was not revealed.

Comment: Your'e also missing a closing `}`  for the function `rotate` ; That hard `return` is *in* the loop.

Comment: Since `cipher` is `0`, `cipher[i]` is `*(((string)0)+i)` which is obviously not right. When `i` is `0`, `cipher[i]` is `*0`!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not indented properly. There is a missing `}` at the end of the `rotate` function, causing the `main` function to be defined inside the body of the `rotate` function. The missing `}` is actually at the end of the `for` block: the `return cipher;` should be outside this block.

Note these other problems:

- you never allocate the `cipher` string.
- you should distinguish uppercase and lowercase letters and use the `%` operator to handle letters larger than `'Z' - key`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *rotate(const char *text, int key) {
    char *cipher = strdup(text);
    for (size_t i = 0; text[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        unsigned char ch = text[i];
        if (isupper(ch)) {
            cipher[i] = 'A' + (ch - 'A' + key) % 26;
        } else
        if (islower(ch)) {
            cipher[i] = 'a' + (ch - 'a' + key) % 26;
        }
        cipher[i] = ch;
    }
    return cipher;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *keystr, *p;
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    char *keystr = argv[1];
    char *p;
    int key = strtol(keystr, &p, 0);
    if (p == keystr || *p != '\0') {
        printf("caesar: invalid key: %s\n", keystr);
        return 1;
    }
    char *text = get_string("Plaintext:  ");
    char *cipher_text = rotate(text, key);
    printf("Ciphertext: %s\n", cipher_text);
    free(cipher_text);
    return 0;
}
```